# python: read beyond end of file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read beyond the EOF in Python, but so far I'm failing (also tried to work with seek to position and read fixed size).

I've found a workaround which only works on Linux (and is quite slow, too) by working with debugfs and subprocess, but this is to slow and does not work on windows.

My Question: is it possible to read a file beyond EOF in python (which works on all platforms)?

Comment: What do expect to accomplish when reading beyond the end? What do you think you will get?

Comment: Do you expect the file to increase in size, and thus the original end-of-file indicator becomes out of date?

Comment: I hope it is not possible, it would be a major security leak

Comment: I am trying to visit Narnia but haven't found the right closet yet.

Comment: I was trying to read the slack space.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. The "file" is loaded into memory, and end of file is the end of that memory. Anything past that would be unreadable and unusable junk, or leftover from a previous memory load, which would be a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't read more bytes than is in the file. "End of file" literally means exactly that.

Comment: well, I was hoping that I could work without a C module.

Answer (score 0):

You can only move to the end using:

```
file.seek(0, 2)
```

Is that you're trying to do?